# Rails App Memory Leak: Nginx + Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks, nginx, unicorn

While testing my app with Jmeter i found that the memory consumption is increasingly high. After running htop i found it very strange that there are two master processes and that each worker process has many childs.

My question is: is this normal or is this possibly the reason for the memory leak (or bloat)?

[image]

Comment: There aren't two masters, it's an [htop feature/bug](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/why-does-htop-show-more-process-than-ps/10403#10403) :)

Comment: Why do you have so many workers? I see 29, 30, 31... you shouldn't have more workers than CPU amount, the only effect would be a used memory increasing. Try with 8 workers (I see you have 8 CPUs)

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't two masters, it's an [`htop` feature/bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/why-does-htop-show-more-process-than-ps/10403#10403) :)

About memory consumption: why do you have so many workers? I see 29, 30, 31... you shouldn't have more workers than CPU amount, the only effect would be a used memory increasing. Try with 8 workers (I see you have 8 CPUs)

Comment: Thx for the response. Unfortunately though, your response made me happy and sad. I was hoping that this could be the reason for the memory leak :( Ps.: 32 workers yielded the highest response rates in our tests. The documentation says that amount of workers should be at LEAST the amount of cpu's. Since i have 7 GB and considering that each worker consumes (initially) approx 120 MB this shouldn't be a problem as long as memory is being released steadily.

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Actually if your web app is mainly I/O more forks can help because the CPU is not overloaded... you're right. I asked you about your Ruby version because of [this](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2014/04/08/ruby-2-1-garbage-collection-ready-for-production), I suggest you to read it

Comment: I just read the article. I'm using 2.1.1 so this is most disturbing.

Comment: If you suspect to be affected by that bug you can try tweaking `RUBY_GC_HEAP_OLDOBJECT_LIMIT_FACTOR` environment variable, as wrote in the post (I'm not affected, so I can't confirm you whether it works or not)